# PHP/MYSQL - Which Join Statement To Use To Simplify My Queries?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have these 2 queries and i would like to join them into one but i am unsure of how to go about it.

Query 1:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$db_tbl_comics." WHERE ".$db_fld_comics_publisher."='".$pub_id."'
AND ".$db_fld_comics_active."='1' GROUP BY ".$db_fld_comics_arc;
```

Query 2:

```
$q2 = mysql_query('SELECT '.$db_fld_arcs_title.' FROM '.$db_tbl_arcs.'
WHERE '.$db_fld_arcs_id.'="'.$result[$db_fld_comics_arc].'"');
```

Comics Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comics` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `arc` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `issue` decimal(5,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `plot` longtext NOT NULL,
  `publisher` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `published` date NOT NULL,
  `cover` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT './images/nopic.jpg',
  `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `views` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `arc` (`arc`,`title`,`issue`,`publisher`)
);
```

Arcs Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `arcs` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `plot` longtext NOT NULL,
  `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`)
);
```

What I need to do is get the Arcs Title from the arcs table for the respective comic arc.

Comment: i would like to know what are the values in arc and title in comics table ,If the title values in both tables  are same then avoid it in comics you could create a constraint foreign key for arc key comics table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `INNER JOIN` for that since I presume that records are present on both tables.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.title
FROM    comics a INNER JOIN arcs b
            on a.id = b.id
WHERE   a.Title = 'VALUEHERE'
```

displays all details from `comics` table and the title of the arc

Comment: Honestly im lost here. What goes in valuehere?!? and the 2 tables are related as so: comics.arc = arc.id

Comment: actually that is an optional condition. (*you can remove it if you no condition*) the value of `valuehere` is for specific title of the comics.

Answer (score 1):

as simple as (joining 2 queries in one, by selecting only the required field and using `IN`):

```
SELECT
    '.$db_fld_arcs_title.'
    FROM '.$db_tbl_arcs.'
    WHERE '.$db_fld_arcs_id.' IN (
        SELECT '.$db_fld_comics_arc.'
            FROM '.$db_tbl_comics.' 
            WHERE '.$db_fld_comics_publisher.'='".$pub_id."'
            AND '.$db_fld_comics_active.'='1' GROUP BY '.$db_fld_comics_arc.'
    )
```

Comment: so i could still pull out all the comic info from the comics table with this query?

Comment: no, it's for title as I see, but you could use `SELECT * FROM ..` in first line

Comment: this is good but i need to pull all the information from the comics table as well.

Comment: then you can use @John Woo's query and modify it to SELECT `a.*, b.*`